# echo is not working in jenkins windows batch command line

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

When i run the echo test in Jenkins windows batch command line and after ran the command it will not show the value and it is giving the below error. 
' c:\jenkins\workspace\test>echo 
 ECHO is on.'

please can you advise how to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error, that's simply what the line

```
echo
```

will show. If you've written something like

```
echo %Variable%
```

then the environment variable `Variable` is not defined. This may be more a problem in how you've set up the script to run in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Can you write you code in your answer?

Probably you have any space when you set your variable value.

For example:

```
set variable = %X

echo %var%
```

You need to change to this:

```
set variable=%X

echo %var%
```